# React is it possible to setState with an function parameter?

Tags: reactjs

Hello i am trying to use a function to set my Modals state and i got alot of modals so what i am doing is trying as this

here is the function call

```
this.openModal('doneModal')
```

that goes here

```
 openModal(state) {
  console.log(state);
  this.setState({state : true}, () => console.log(this.state.doneModal));
}
```

when i log the parameter state it says doneModal as expected but it does not set the state as the second console.log is still false.

if i change to

```
this.setState({doneModal:true)} the console log shows true. is it not possible to setState as such?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add square bracket `[]` to your code:

```
openModal(state) {
  console.log(state);
  this.setState({ [state]: true}, () => console.log(this.state.doneModal));
}
```

Comment: it worked! is this brackets just for when setting state? i have never come across using them in React

Comment: It has nothing in common with setting state or React. It is just a syntax for updating object having dynamic `key` value.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the state dynamically you need to wrap your dynamic variable with `[]` like

```
openModal(state) {
  console.log(state);
  this.setState({[state] : true}, () => console.log(this.state.doneModal));
}
```